# Prevent Text Spoofing - Best methods

Tags: mobile, wireless, spoofing, sms

In an enterprise environment we have been inundated with spoof texts appearing to be from the corporate office.

After much research it appears Verizon isn't able to assist. Just wondering if anyone has experienced this and best methods for reducing the risk and re-occurrence to my staff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't really a way to prevent it. It's an inherent weakness of the SS7 system. However, you can try to educate your users to not fall for these scams. Maybe you can even hack back and try to play their game and trick them.

Comment: SS7 meaning [Signaling System 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_System_No._7)

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'appearing to be from the corporate office' I assume you mean they are spoofing a sender name and not the number? For example the SMSs come through as 'Organisation HR' or something.

If that is the case, then these messages still come from an associated real number. Its likely that the sender doesn't own their own infrastructure capable of doing this and is just using an API service such as [ClockworkSMS](https://www.clockworksms.com/), which can SMS anyone with an arbitrary name displayed.

What you need to do is simple:

1. find the number of the sender by showing the contact details of the sender on the phone.
2. find out what service that sent it (such as ClockworkSMS - do a google search)
3. send them an email warning them that you do not want anymore SMSs sent with your organisation name or to your organisation.
4. block the real sender number in your corporate MDM solution if you have one.

As a side, it is not possible to block named-number SMSs on iOS. I think its a bug, but basically if you view the sender number the block option will be greyed out. So someone is free to harass you via named numbers on iOS all day long :( I'll report it to Apple.